# only run validate after submit data on CI4

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-4

i create login form with CI4 and bootstrap, but the form always show validation error before data input, i has been add `is-invalid` logic in views file.

[image]

here my controller code

```php
$session = session();
if ($session->get('email')) {
    if ($session->get('role_id') == 1) {
        return redirect()->to('/');
    } else {
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
$isValid = $this->validate([
    'email' => 'required|trim|valid_email',
    'password' => 'required|trim'
]);
if (!$isValid) {
    $data['title'] = 'Login';
    echo view('template/auth_header', $data);
    echo view('auth/login', ['validation' => $this->validator]);
    echo view('template/auth_footer');
} else {
    $this->_login();
}
```

and here my login views

```html
<form class="user" method="post" action="<?= base_url('auth/login') ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user <?= ($validation->hasError('email')) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address..." name="email" value="<?= set_value('email'); ?>">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            <?= $validation->getError('email'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user <?= ($validation->hasError('password')) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            <?= $validation->getError('password'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
        Login
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: If you're receiving form validation errors **before** submitting the form, that means *front-end form validation* is the closest culprit. Share or inspect your front-end JavaScript/Bootstrap/jQuery source code. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/

Answer (score 0):

You need to send errors only when form is submitted else clear validator and load view, below is example hope this will clear this confusion

```
$session = session();
if ($session->get('email')) {
    if ($session->get('role_id') == 1) {
        return redirect()->to('/');
    } else {
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
$this->validate([
    'email' => 'required|trim|valid_email',
    'password' => 'required|trim'
]);

if ($this->validate->withRequest($this->request)->run() == false) {

    if ($this->request->getMethod() === 'post') {
        $data["validation"] = $this->validator;
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('errors', $this->validate->getErrors());
    } else {
        $this->validate->reset();
        $data['title'] = 'Login';
        echo view('template/auth_header', $data);
        echo view('auth/login', ['validation' => $this->validator]);
        echo view('template/auth_footer');
    }
} else {
    $this->_login();
}
```